# Mac OS: Java not using complete path variable [ProcessBuilder]

Tags: java, macos, processbuilder

I am trying to use a process builder in order to run a shell command from Java under Mac OS. When executing the code, I get an error, that the according executable cannot be found. This is clearly a problem with the path variable, as the exact same command works perfectly in the terminal.

When comparing my system path variable and the output of

```
System.getenv()
```

, one can see that "/usr/local/bin" is missing, although it is in the system path variable.

Does anyone know why this is and if so: How can I change it?

I also tried to directly access the according executable via a absolute path, but that won't work since the executable calls others which are only in "/usr/local/bin".

Thanks for your time in advance! :)

Comment: There are numerous questions in relation to the MacOS environment with possible workarounds. You could always actually use the `ProcessBuilder.environment()` and alter the PATH environment variable before launching it explicitly.

Comment: The ProcessBuilder.environment() does only change the environment of the spawned processes, but not for the spawning itself.

Comment: You use the full path for the execution.

Comment: Can't do that as I wrote in the post :(.

Comment: You use processbuilder to add `/usr/local/bin` to the `PATH` environment variable, so that everything that is called by the program will be able to find things in `/usr/local/bin`; then you call the program via an absolute path.